# Database Seeding in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1. I am trying to run database seeding command.

My table name is **users**

My migration file is as below

2015_11_09_194832_create_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

UsersTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

// DatabaseSeeder.php
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        DB::table('users');
        $users = array(
                ['name' => 'Ryan Chenkie', 'email' => 'ryanchenkie@gmail.com', 'password' => Hash::make('secret')],
                ['name' => 'Chris Sevilleja', 'email' => 'chris@scotch.io', 'password' => Hash::make('secret')],
                ['name' => 'Holly Lloyd', 'email' => 'holly@scotch.io', 'password' => Hash::make('secret')],
                ['name' => 'Adnan Kukic', 'email' => 'adnan@scotch.io', 'password' => Hash::make('secret')],
        );

        // Loop through each user above and create the record for them in the database
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            User::create($user);
        }
        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

While I am trying to run seeding command **php artisan db:seed** I am getting below error.

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist
```

Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Comment: Both classes are in the same, global namespace, so "use" is not needed. Try running "composer dump-autoload" - it should reload the list of seeders.

Comment: After new seeder was created  you should run `composer  dumpautoload` in project root

Comment: As both above users commented you need to use `composer dump-autoload` with your project root. You can use the respective command within terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run in to this issue a few time when I've added seeders either in a new project or to an existing project where I want to add some data to test.

Both jedrzej.kurylo and Alex were on the right track, `composer dump-autoload` which will regenerate your autoload files and include the seeder(s) you've just added.